# Why do we need in general mathematical physics only orthogonal transformations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Why do we need in mathematical physics (as I know in English it is called Partial Differential Equations) orthogonal transformations coordinates?

(for example, the heat equation and the wave equation)

I know that the Laplacian is invariant under such transformations. (In other words it does not change its form).

However, what's the difference?

let's say I have an equation:

$u'_t=\Delta u$, and condition $u\bigr|_{t=0}=e^{-(x+y-z)^2}$, and task is to find $u(t,x,y,z)$

First of all, I should do change of variables:
$\xi=\xi(x,y,z) = x + y - z $

(And you can see that such change of variable can't be orthogonal already! Because $\{b_{ij}\}=A^{t}\cdot A \neq E$, since we have $b_{11}=1\cdot1+1\cdot1+(-1)\cdot(-1)=3\neq 1$)

By the way, everything is solving easily. Let's do it.

And after change of variables we should try to find solution as $\hat u(\xi,t)$

then I say $u'_t = \Delta_{x,y,z}\hat u(\xi(x,y,z),t) =3 \hat u_{\xi\xi}$.

And that's why $\hat u (\xi,t)$ is a solution to equation $u'_t = 3 \hat u_{\xi\xi} $ with condition $\hat u\bigr|_{t=0}=e^{-\xi^2}$

That can be easily solved.

But my teacher said that we should use only orthogonal transformations!

For what?

I say nothing about about $\eta, \zeta$.

You can say: "ask this teacher, nobody knows what he meant!". But I will not see him next two weeks.

Comment: Do you care about rigid transformations? That is, transformations that preserve the Euclidean distance ... Do $u$, $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$ have specific meanings for your model?

Comment: I have no special meaning for it. (Because I have no model - it is just equations)
I don't know for what I should care about rigid transformations, if I should. That is my question!

Comment: The teacher probably recommended the use of orthogonal transformations because they transform the Laplacian in a simple manner. If the change of coordinates is non-orthogonal, the Laplacian may contain mixed derivatives $like \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\xi\partial \eta}$. Those tend to be messy.

Comment: You refer to those equations as "heat equation" and "wave equation." To me those terms seem to carry a lot of meaning. Maybe $x$, $y$, $z$ are space coordinates and $t$ is a time coordinate? And if so, maybe it's not "just equations"?

Comment: @CatalinZara But It is subject of mathematical physics - here we don't think about physical meaning. Just math.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes, I agree with you. I know that. But See question carefully.

$\Delta u(\xi,t) $ cannot depend on $\eta, \zeta$. So, is it really important for solving this equations?

Comment: @Dida Maybe thinking about the meaning of the math you're doing is also important ... Can I use your "But It is subject of mathematical physics - here we don't think about physical meaning. Just math." comment?

Comment: No, it is not, I agree. We choose orthogonal coordinate systems for computational convenience.

Comment: Oh, now I've realized that in English this subject is called Partial Differential Equations. and now you should not think about meaning.

By the way, of course, t is analogy of time and should be $t>0$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro this is a good version. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Dida Partial Differential Equations is not just about mathematical physics. I'm sorry to learn that you think that one "should not think about meaning." I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @CatalinZara But mathematicians don't care about meaning of variable at all. It is all about equations, limit, integrals, derivatives and etc.

Well, let' think about meaning. Why my equation will be stopped to be usual equations. What the difference?

Comment: Heh, when I met him, he said: "It is just convient to explain. You can use any of linear transformations"